# hspace not working inside mdframed

Tags: horizontal-alignment, mdframed, shadows

I am trying to use `\hspace` to align text inside `mdframed` box. However, `\hspace` seems to not working inside `mdframed` box. Text in the `mdframed` is somehow is aligned to center. Why is `\hspace` not working here ?

```
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newmdenv[shadow=true,shadowcolor=black,font=\sffamily, align=right, leftmargin=10pt]{shadowbox}


\begin{shadowbox}
\hspace{2cm} 90   \hspace{1cm}  [NOP]   \newline
\hspace{2cm} 8bff \hspace{1cm}  [MOV EDI, EDI] (FUNCTION ENTRY) \newline
\hspace{2cm} 90   \hspace{1cm}  [NOP]   \newline
\hspace{2cm} 90   \hspace{1cm}  [NOP] \newline
\hspace{2cm} 90   \hspace{1cm}  [NOP] \newline
\hspace{2cm} 90   \hspace{1cm}  [NOP] \newline
\hspace{2cm} 8bff \hspace{1cm}  [MOV EDI, EDI] (FUNCTION ENTRY) \newline
\hspace{2cm} 55   \hspace{1cm}  [PUSH EBP] \newline
\hspace{2cm} 8bec \hspace{1cm} [MOV EBP, ESP] \newline
\end{shadowbox}
```

Following is the result I am getting now :

[image]

Comment: As far as I know the first `\hspace` should be `\hspace*`, because there is no text before the command. Further it seems that your problem has to do with the align option of your mdframed environment. I personally would use a tabular inside the mdframed environment to align the op codes.

Comment: Unusual approach. Why you not use table for this formatting. To me with it is more natural an of course more easy way.

Answer (score 2):

After `\newline` spacing such as `\hspace` is ignored; you can force it to work with `\hpsace*` instead.  Try this little example to see what happens:

```
\noindent
Text\newline
\hspace{2cm}text\newline
\hspace*{2cm}text.
```

[image: Sample output]

However, what you probably want is a `tabbing` environment, otherwise the columns are not going to line up.  Compare the first example below with `tabbing` with the second, which is what your modified input would give:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newmdenv[shadow=true,shadowcolor=black,font=\sffamily, align=right,
  leftmargin=10pt]{shadowbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{shadowbox}
  \begin{tabbing}
    \hspace{2cm} \= 90   \hspace{1cm} \= [NOP] \\
    \> 8bff \>  [MOV EDI, EDI] (FUNCTION ENTRY) \\
    \> 90   \>  [NOP]   \\
    \> 90   \>  [NOP] \\
    \> 90   \>  [NOP] \\
    \> 90   \>  [NOP] \\
    \> 8bff \>  [MOV EDI, EDI] (FUNCTION ENTRY) \\
    \> 55   \>  [PUSH EBP] \\
    \> 8bec \> [MOV EBP, ESP] \\
  \end{tabbing}
\end{shadowbox}

\begin{shadowbox}
\hspace*{2cm} 90   \hspace{1cm}  [NOP]   \newline
\hspace*{2cm} 8bff \hspace{1cm}  [MOV EDI, EDI] (FUNCTION ENTRY) \newline
\hspace*{2cm} 90   \hspace{1cm}  [NOP]   \newline
\hspace*{2cm} 90   \hspace{1cm}  [NOP] \newline
\hspace*{2cm} 90   \hspace{1cm}  [NOP] \newline
\hspace*{2cm} 90   \hspace{1cm}  [NOP] \newline
\hspace*{2cm} 8bff \hspace{1cm}  [MOV EDI, EDI] (FUNCTION ENTRY) \newline
\hspace*{2cm} 55   \hspace{1cm}  [PUSH EBP] \newline
\hspace*{2cm} 8bec \hspace{1cm} [MOV EBP, ESP] \newline
\end{shadowbox}

\end{document}
```

The first line of `tabbing` provides a template, with `\=` setting the tabstops.  On subsequent lines `\>` moves to the next tab.

Answer (score 1):

or by using tabularx:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newmdenv[shadow=true,shadowcolor=black,font=\sffamily, 
          align=right, leftmargin=10pt]{shadowbox}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{shadowbox}% <-- just for showing only the shadowbox
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}


    \begin{document}
\begin{shadowbox}
    \begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{>{\setlength\hsize{0.5\hsize}\qquad}XXX}
90   &  [NOP]           &                       \\
8bff &  [MOV EDI, EDI]  &   (FUNCTION ENTRY)    \\
90   &  [NOP]           &                       \\
90   &  [NOP]           &                       \\
90   &  [NOP]           &                       \\
90   &  [NOP]           &                       \\
8bff &  [MOV EDI, EDI]  &   (FUNCTION ENTRY)    \\
55   &  [PUSH EBP]      &                       \\
8bec &  [MOV EBP, ESP]  &
    \end{tabularx}
\end{shadowbox}
    \end{document}
```

[image]